# Install MySQLDump for MySQL 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysqldump, mysql8

I am trying to install mysqldump on a Azure hosted Ubuntu VM.

During the build process I attempt the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mysql-client-8.0
```

This results in the following error:

```
Unable to locate package mysql-client-8.0
```

When I look at the package on packages.ubuntu.com, it is listed under Ubuntu Focal 20.04LTS (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mysql-client-8.0)

If I change the installation command to:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mysql-client
```

It installed mysql-client-5.7 which isn't running properly. Is the mysql-client version for the appropriate database tied to the Ubuntu server? Should the 5.7 client work correctly with MySQL 8.0?

Comment: How did you get 5.7? Do you have third party repos or repos from a previous Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get 8.0 client tools (or server) you have to install the official MySQL repo for apt.
I recommend to follow this [detailed guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/).

TLDR;

1. go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/
2. find the link for the latest deb package (use that in the following steps)
3. on your server:
4. `wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb`
5. `sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb`
6. `sudo apt-get update`
7. `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`
8. `mysqldump --version` (should say Ver 8.x.x)

Comment: It only suggests either server or tools like "MySQL suite, including connectors, MySQL Workbench, MySQL Utilities and MySQL router", nothing about mysqldump

Answer (score 11):

Forget MySql packages, use MariaDb packages instead:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-client
```

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/

Comment: This tip is handy for folks on ~Ubuntu 20.04+ and need to use MySQL 5.7 client (unavailable without adding repos).  Instead, install with something like `sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mariadb-client-10.3`  since MariaDB 10.3 is parallel to MySQL 5.7 and is still available natively

Comment: But why are you running MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 20.04+ it defaults to MySQL 8.0 and the client install works fine: `sudo apt install mysql-client`